# Event handling confusing

Tags: solidity, events, etherscan

Given is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract changeSomVal{
    address owner;
    bool test;    
    event showBool(bool showBool);

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        if(msg.sender == owner)
            _;
    }

    function () public payable{
        emit showBool(test);
    }

    function changeBoolTrue () public onlyOwner { // returns (bool)
            test = true;
            emit showBool(test);
    }

    function changeBoolFalse () public onlyOwner {
            test = false;
            emit showBool(test);
    }
}
```

On etherscan it always returns a 64 chars length 0...0 eventLog. It doesn´t matter wich function was called. I also tried it with `uint8 (1,2)` for `changeBoolTrue() -> test = 1` and `changeBoolFalse() -> test = 2`. I tired it with a return too: `function changeBoolTrue () public onlyOwner returns (bool)`. The eventLog throws always the same.

On remix it looks fine. But in the reality it doesn´t work. What´s wrong?

Comment: Etherscan link?

Comment: I think it will be helpful if you provide a complete code for smart contract

Comment: Thanks, now the full code is added. At the moment I can´t submit a transaction that you could take a look on it. In a few hours it is possible. But, as I wrote every eventLog contains a simple 64 length 0 hex-string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't *really* see anything wrong with what you have written.  But, convention dictates that you should start event names with upper case characters.

Another pinch-point could be that you've named the bool parameter the same as the event.  Given that you don't need to reference the argument, I would adjust your event to look like the following;

`event ShowBool(bool);`

and adjust your `emit` calls accordingly.

**Edit0:**

I deployed your fixed contract on Rinkeby, [here](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xa7c28c84ed56186ccffd469a4abe3ccd7f1b7465).  You can see that EtherScan has verified that the source matches the bytecodes [here](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xa7c28c84ed56186ccffd469a4abe3ccd7f1b7465#code).

The reason for all the transactions is that I have called the fallback—`function ()`—in between calls to `changeBoolTrue()` and `changeBoolFalse()`, which show that the state of `test` is preserved in the contract between calls.

Comment: I have fixed the code. The first call to this contract was `changeBoolTrue()`. The same again (etherscan eventLog): 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: Great! - It seems to work. And thanks so far for your efforts. But ... I can´t get it what have done that it works. How to call the fallback-function?

Comment: In the `Run` tab, in Remix, the list of callable functions is visible at the bottom right, in the `Deployed Contracts` panel (you can click the red box and verify the transaction).  Alternatively, if you send a small amount of ETH to the contract, the fallback function will be called.